# Selecting Elements that have multiple class whilst using JSoup

Tags: java, html, json, jsoup

I am parsing some tables from a website, and specifically I am trying to extract the following cells by class name:

```
Elements e=d.select("span[class=bld lrg red]");

for (Element element : e) {
System.out.println(element.text());}
```

this code is giving me some values which is given as Price in the web site. but some cases, I want to take price from a different class rather than `"span[class=bld lrg red]"`.

**I mean is the "bld lrg red" class is empty then i want to take value from "span[class=price]"**

How can I use 'or' in this case.. I mean if the "bld lrg red" class has value then take that price or take the "price" class value.

Comment: Can page have both `span[class=bld lrg red]` or `span[class=price]` elements? If not then you can try using `span[class=bld lrg red], span[class=price]`. Otherwise you will find both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `regex` to select the required elements in from your web page using `jsoup` too, there you can use and 'OR' condition to specify what you are looking for;

Example:

```
Elements e = d.select("span[class~=(?i)(bld lrg red|price)]");
```

The above regex would select your `span` elements with `class`selector directly matching `bld lrg red` OR `price` (case insensitive).

Refer to here for details: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Now you may want to iterate over the elements and select which are not blank, null, both and so on.

**EDIT:** As per the comments, `price class` is not held by a `span` element. To get over it, you can use:

```
Elements e = d.select("span[class=bld lrg red],del[class=price]");
```

Comment: this will work if both are span class.but in this case one class is <del class="price"> and the other one is <span class="bld lrg red">. so how will i use this methode?

Comment: @sarath yes, in your question you've specified both are span elements with changing class values

Comment: @sarath check the edit above, you can specify both elements individually which is an effective 'OR'

Comment: thanks PopoFibo.. this works fine.. thanks for help.. now i am getting both... so can i use many number of classes using comma(,) like the sample given above.

Comment: there is a problem still exists.. if one of the class has price then i dont need the other class value.. for example u see some sites has original price and then discount price for same product. Consider Original price is coming in "bld lrg red" and discount price is in "Price". But for all the product there wont be any discount. so If "Price" is available then take that and if no "Price value then take "bld lrg red". now in the above sample both values are displaying for each product. hope u understood the problem..

Comment: @sarath when you are iterating over all these elements, you can check for `element.className().equals(...)` to check to which class the element belongs.