# unable to extract contents from html using jsoup in java?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup to extract the contents from the below HTML code in the following < td > tags which has class css-sched-table-title and css-sched-waypoints. But i am not able to understand whats going wrong can someone help ?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("somelink.html");
    Elements row = doc.select(".css-sched-table-title td");
    Iterator<Element> iterator = row.listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
       Element element = iterator.next();
        String value = element.text();
        System.out.println("value : " + value);
    }
```

.

```
  <tr>
        <td ALIGN="CENTER" COLSPAN="16"  CLASS="css-sched-table-title"><b>Saturday - </b><b>Afternoon</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr VALIGN="BOTTOM">
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Townline and Southern</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Clearbrook and Blueridge</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Clearbrook and South Fraser</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Ar. Bourquin Exchange</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Lv. Bourquin Exchange</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Downtown Abbotsford</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">McMillan and Old Yale</TD>
        <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Sandy Hill and Old Clayburn</TD>
    </tr>
```

Comment: did you try "td.css-sched-table-title"?

Comment: Hi Nishant that did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single `td` tag with `css-sched-table-title` but a list with `css-sched-waypoints`.

Also, aligning to the correct syntax it should be `Elements row = doc.select("td.css-sched-waypoints");`, refer to [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

**Note: `html` file is used as is is invalid and `jsoup` would not interpret it as valid table html contents. I had to enclose the content above within `<table></table>` tags.**

When I try the below code with your `html` file:

```
Elements row = doc.select("td.css-sched-waypoints");
    Element title = doc.select("td.css-sched-table-title").first();

    System.out.println(title.text());
    Iterator<Element> iterator = row.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Element element = iterator.next();
        String id = element.attr("id");
        String classes = element.attr("class");
        String value = element.text();
        System.out.println("Id : " + id + ", classes : " + classes
                + ", value : " + value);
    }
```

I get,

```
Saturday - Afternoon
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Townline and Southern
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Clearbrook and Blueridge
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Clearbrook and South Fraser
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Ar. Bourquin Exchange
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Lv. Bourquin Exchange
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Downtown Abbotsford
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : McMillan and Old Yale
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Sandy Hill and Old Clayburn
```

Comment: Hi PopoFibo thanks for the explanation i got it corrected and now it works fine.

Comment: hi PopoFibo one quick question is it possible to  Elements row = doc.select("td.css-sched-waypoints"); Elements times = doc.select("td.css-sched-times");  instead of having 2 separate elements just have them in one Elements instance ?

Comment: @dev_marshell08 yes, you sure can - to start with refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694216/selecting-elements-that-have-multiple-class-whilst-using-jsoup/21694612#21694612

Comment: Hi again PopoFibo tried but i got stuck i am little confused ... can you look at this thread for me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011133/how-to-parse-html-file-using-jsoup-with-multiple-class-name-element

Comment: @dev_marshell08 I have responded to your question there with a valid use of a `Selector` syntax