# how to parse html file using Jsoup with multiple class-name element?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

the below java code works fine for html file with class for eg css-sched-table-title.

However i have multiple class names to find for in the html file eg css-sched-waypoints , css-sched-times. How do i combine the search using getElementsByClass method in jsoup. I don't want to write the code multiple times because I want to preserver the order. My point is i want something like

**doc.getElementsByClass("css-sched-table-title" || doc.getElementsByClass("css-sched-waypoints" );**

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

    Elements ele = doc.getElementsByClass("css-sched-table-title");
    for (Element link : ele) {

       String linkText = link.text();
       System.out.println(linkText);    

   }
```

.

```
<tr ALIGN="CENTER">
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:15</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:20</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:24</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:34</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:34</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:40</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:46</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
           <td CLASS="css-sched-times">6:54</td>
</tr>
<tr VALIGN="BOTTOM">
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Townline and Southern</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Clearbrook and Blueridge</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Clearbrook and South Fraser</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Ar. Bourquin Exchange</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Lv. Bourquin Exchange</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Downtown Abbotsford</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">McMillan and Old Yale</TD>
           <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
           <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="100" CLASS="css-sched-waypoints">Sandy Hill and Old Clayburn</TD>
   </tr>

 <tr ALIGN="CENTER">
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:12</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:17</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:21</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:31</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:34</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:40</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:46</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">&nbsp;</td>
      <td CLASS="css-sched-times">8:54</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: And how should the result of this combined call look like? Simply select two `Elements` and combine the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking cues from your earlier query, when I try and combine the 3 `td`s through a valid `Selector` syntax, I get the result you are expecting.

`doc.select("td[class=css-sched-table-title], td[class=css-sched-waypoints], td[class=css-sched-times]")`

**Note**, you can combine multiple conditions within your selector syntax like this `Elements row = doc.select("td[class=css-sched-table-title], td[class=css-sched-waypoints], td[class=css-sched-times]");` which effectively becomes your `OR` operator.

```
Elements row = doc.select("td[class=css-sched-table-title], td[class=css-sched-waypoints], td[class=css-sched-times]");
        System.out.println("::Total Count::" + row.size());

        Iterator<Element> iterator = row.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Element element = iterator.next();
            String id = element.attr("id");
            String classes = element.attr("class");
            String value = element.text();
            System.out.println("Id : " + id + ", classes : " + classes
                    + ", value : " + value);
        }
```

Gives,

```
::Total Count::25
Id : , classes : css-sched-table-title, value : Saturday - Afternoon
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Townline and Southern
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Clearbrook and Blueridge
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Clearbrook and South Fraser
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Ar. Bourquin Exchange
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Lv. Bourquin Exchange
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Downtown Abbotsford
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : McMillan and Old Yale
Id : , classes : css-sched-waypoints, value : Sandy Hill and Old Clayburn
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:15
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:20
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:24
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:34
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:34
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:40
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:46
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value :  
Id : , classes : css-sched-times, value : 6:54
```

For the detailed usage of the `Selector` syntax refer to [here.](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)