# Python web scraping to extract both the dates and the fixture details together

Tags: python, web-scraping

So using this code I can extract both the dates and the fixture details.  What I cannot do is extract them together.

The end goal here is to make an indexed and dated list of fixtures in a dataframe or table that I can then work with ... for example using todays date to determine this weekends fixtures

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import pprint
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

# sample web page
print(colored('#Step1','green'))



url = "https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-fixtures"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#headlines = soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'cd__headline-text'}, limit=10)
#for headline in headlines:
 #   print(headline.text)
 
#print (soup)
#soup.prettify()
#print(soup.prettify())

soup.find_all('div')

tablechp = soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'fixres__body'})#[2] #add this to filter for this item
for tablechp in tablechp:
    print(tablechp.text)
#eventnum=tablechp.text

#widgetLite-10
#fixres matches-block--large

print(colored('#Step2','green'))

tabletitles = soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'fixres__header2'})#[2]
for tabletitles in tabletitles:
    print(tabletitles.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple criteria selection to retrieve both classes in a row.

Here [is an example is java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011133/how-to-parse-html-file-using-jsoup-with-multiple-class-name-element) but filter syntax is same.

Then, you'll be able to choose both values.

Comment: Hi, thnaks for that, able to help with the code?

Comment: I can't acces this site, can you share a sample in your question ?

Comment: Cannot upload a screenshot